# SD Card partitioning got messed while installing Ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, sd-card

I recently shifted from windows to Ubuntu. I got a problem of SD Card partitioning. I run the sudo fdisk /dev/sdc1 and tried to manage it. I want only a single partition of 32 GB so that my sdcard works normally on any pc. Here is the details of current state of my sdcard. Please help me by telling the commands so that I can achieve the desired result.
[YOU CAN SEE THE CURRENT STATE HERE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CY41f.png)

It is currently having 1 sector of type extended and my sdcard is not detected on either wndows or linux

Comment: sdc1 is an extended partition (ie. logical), meaning it'll usually be subdivided into partitions that have data.  What you've shown isn't very valuable without what's within the extended partition  (which given the size, & start & end; it'll be empty).   Your partition table may have been lost; needs to be re-created.  SDcards are usually not built for heavy use

Comment: Its empty completely. There are no logical pertitions.

Comment: What should i do now? If I type n to make a new primary partition then it shows the error that all primary partitions are occupied

Comment: How to re-create partition table properly? please help in that